# Unexpected behaviour when using fixed layout tables with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

This relatively straightforward code snippet makes the table stretch to 1000000px. Confirmed in Chrome, FF, Safari, Safari TP, IE11, Edge 13 and Edge 14. Firefox is the only browser which works as I would expect — container, child and table and document body all occupy the same width.

https://jsfiddle.net/Dremora/gorp2Lqz/4/

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    <table>
      <tr><td>This table is 1000000px wide</td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

What is going on here? Why 1000000px? Which browsers got it right?

*Clarification*: I'm not looking for a way to make it work — I got it working before posting the question. I want to understand why it behaves the way it does, preferably with a reference to the part of the CSS spec which explains this growth, or to browsers' issue trackers if it's a bug.

Comment: There is no `flex-basis` defined. `flex-shrink` & `flex-grow` should really be used when there are other flexible elements in relation with it, when there aren't, you can expect weird results like this. What you're declaring here is "shrink `child` 0 times smaller than the rest". Have a look at this fiddle to get a better idea of what's cracking: https://jsfiddle.net/gorp2Lqz/3/

Comment: The width in your layout may be infinite, and the 1000000px may be the browser limit.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError using `flex-shrink: 1` or `flex-basis: 100%` solves the issue, but I'm trying to understand the existing behaviour. Quote often CSS can be very quirky but its behaviour can always be explained.
@Michael_B it probably is some browser limit — but is this behaviour part of the spec? Is it intended or just a common browser bug?

Comment: spec: [*CSS theoretically supports infinite precision and infinite ranges for all value types; however in reality implementations have finite capacity. UAs should support reasonably useful ranges and precisions.*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#numeric-types)

Comment: you need to remove table {width:100%} to solve the issue.

Comment: change "flex: 0 0 auto;" to "flex: 0 auto;", its solved your problem.